# does * {margin:0; padding:0;} affect HTML?

Tags: html, css

I currently have:

```
html, *{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Is the html part unnecessary?

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the source metrics and see that just the *{} would have done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, in order to work in browsers that don't support universal selector. For list of supporting broswers see [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector#compatibilitysection)

Comment: just another small question: `body div p {...}` what exactly will affect that line? (will body>div>div>p be affected?. By the way, useful link thanks

Answer (score 1):

No `*` is a universal selector, it selects all of the elements and applies the `margin: 0; padding: 0;`. Adding the html tag is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations in practice, the `html` part makes no difference. But logically it does, and this might matter in some circumstances, due to the **specificity** rules in the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

To take an artificial example, if another style sheet being applied sets

```
* { padding-left: 1em; }
```

(rather odd indeed, but possible), then it would have no effect on the `html` element if the `html` part is present in your stylesheet. But if both rules have just the universal selector `*`, the effect depends on the mutual order of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `<html>` will be affected because it is also an *Element*. It is the **ROOT** of your HTML document.

The `*` is called the *Universal Selector*. It's purpose is to select **ALL** the elements in the page, regardless of where and how they are nested.